# Angular UI Router - state query string parameter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a very similar scenario to the angular-ui-router demo app: whenever the user tries to access a state that requires auth, there's a hook which redirects him to the login state. The additional requirement is that someone might want to access a state via URL with an additional querystring parameter: `username` which should be auto-populated in the login page's corresponding input.

My states structure is like so:

- there is a `shell` abstract state which is parent to all other states similar to the `app` state in the demo app
- this `shell` state has `url: '?username'`  (if I understand correctly this parameter should then be inherited by all other states)
- my `login` component has a binding `username: '<'`
- the `login` state has a `resolve` like so `username: $transition$ => $transition$.params().username`

The whole login/redirect mechanism works perfectly. The only problem is that in the `login`'s state `resolve` the `params().username` is undefined even if in the browser I go to a link like `http://mysite/#/somestate?username=foo`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how I can achieve what I'm after?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question: the problem was actually in the login redirect hook. There I was redirecting to the login state with `state.target('login', params, {location: false})` and I was getting the `params` from `transition.router.stateService.params` which never had valid values.

Just trying stuff out I found that actually `transition.params()` gives me the correct parameter values, so I can now redirect with those params and it works fine.

I do have one issue still though: I would ideally like that after login I redirect back to the originally requested state and clear these params from the querystring. Anyone know if that is possible/supported?